# Rock Paper and Scissors in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to coding and my Rock Paper and Scissors game that i've created isn't working as intended. 
If someone enters the word rock, paper or scissors, then the programme works as intended. 
However, when the someone enters a word other than rock, paper or scissors the programme should say "I don't understand, please try again" and prompt the user to enter another input, which it does, but then instead of continuing and working as intended the programme ends. Here is the code:

```
# The game of Rock Paper Scissors

import random

choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors']
computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
selections = 'The computer chose ' + computer_choice + ' so'
computer_score = 0
user_score = 0

def choose_option():
    user_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors. (q to quit)\n>>> ')
    while user_choice != 'q':    
        if user_choice in ['ROCK', 'Rock', 'rock', 'R', 'r']:
            user_choice = 'rock'
        elif user_choice in ['PAPER', 'Paper', 'paper', 'P', 'p']:
            user_choice = 'paper'
        elif user_choice in ['SCISSORS','Scissors', 'scissors', 'S', 's']:
            user_choice = 'scissors'
        else:
            print("I don't understand, please try again.")
            choose_option()           
        return user_choice

user_choice = choose_option()

while user_choice != 'q':
    if user_choice == computer_choice:
        print(selections + ' it\'s a tie')
    elif (user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'scissors'):
        user_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you won! :)')
    elif (user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'rock'):
        user_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you won! :)')
    elif (user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'paper'):
        user_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you won! :)')   
    elif (user_choice == 'rock' and computer_choice == 'paper'):
        computer_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you lost :(')
    elif (user_choice == 'paper' and computer_choice == 'scissors'):
        computer_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you lost :(')
    elif (user_choice == 'scissors' and computer_choice == 'rock'):
        computer_score += 1
        print(selections + ' you lost :(')
    else: 
        break
    print('You: ' + str(user_score) + "    VS    " + "Computer: " + str(computer_score))
    computer_choice = random.choice(choices)
    selections = 'The computer chose ' + computer_choice + ' so'
    user_choice = choose_option()
```

Comment: You need to return from the recursive call, i.e. `return choose_option()` in the `else` clause.

Comment: As a side note, you can save yourself some typing with `if user_choice.lower() in ['rock','r']:`

Comment: or even use regex like - ```if re.search(r'(scissors|s)', user_choice, flags=re.I)```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seemed to be caused by calling the function inside the function. This solved it for me:

```
def choose_option():
   user_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors. (q to quit)\n>>> ')
   while user_choice != 'q':    
     if user_choice in ['ROCK', 'Rock', 'rock', 'R', 'r']:
        user_choice = 'rock'
        return user_choice
     elif user_choice in ['PAPER', 'Paper', 'paper', 'P', 'p']:
        return user_choice
     elif user_choice in ['SCISSORS','Scissors', 'scissors', 'S', 's']:
        return user_choice
     else:
        while user_choice.lower() not in ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "s","r","p","q"]:
            print("I don't understand, please try again.")
            user_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors. (q to quit)\n>>> ')
```

This way, if the computer does not like the input it can just request another one.
Also I would recommend using 
`if user_choice.lower() in []`, just a little easier than typing in all the options.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
else:
            print("I don't understand, please try again.")
            choose_option()
```

you can use

```
while user_choice != 'q':    
        user_choice = input('Please choose Rock, Paper or Scissors. (q to quit)\n>>> ')
        if user_choice in ['ROCK', 'Rock', 'rock', 'R', 'r']:
            user_choice = 'rock'
        elif user_choice in ['PAPER', 'Paper', 'paper', 'P', 'p']:
            user_choice = 'paper'
        elif user_choice in ['SCISSORS','Scissors', 'scissors', 'S', 's']:
            user_choice = 'scissors'
        else:
            print("I don't understand, please try again.")
            continue          
        return user_choice
```

`continue` will cause the program to skip the rest of the loop (here, skipping the `return`) and continuing with the next iteration of the `while` loop (going back up to `user_choice = ...`).  Also note that I think there's another bug where if `user_choice` is `"q"`, the result is not actually returned.